# Какие решения Вы используете для разработки мобильной версии сайта?

Tags: mobile, html

Недавно пришлось заняться этим вопросом. Решил с помощью bootstrap, смотрел в сторону jQuery mobile, но так и не понял смысл использования этого фреймворка. Предположим что нас интересуют apple и android устройства.

Вопросы:

1. Как Вы реализуете определение мобильного устройства, есть ли какой-то универсальный способ / скрипт? (в случае если уже есть сайт, с которого надо перекинуть пользователя на мобильную версию)
2. Какой фреймворк используете для разработки мобильной версии?
3. Делаете отдельно сайт для мобильных и для планшетников или предпочитаете адаптивный дизайн?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Вот так](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=identify+mobile+device+javascript),
2. [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/),
3. Адаптивный дизайн, разве что не стоит задача подстраиваться под Ч/Б телефоны и иже с ними.

Нынче всякие Андроиды и Айфоны справляются со сложной вёрсткой и стилями не хуже остальных. Нужно только помнить про **события мыши**, которых в мобильных девайсах нет при написании скриптов и стилей.

Нужно помнить про **разрешение матрицы** мобильных устройств, особенно когда глаза будут округляться при виде пикселизованных картинок на handheld-девайсе, которые в десктопном браузере выглядят вполне нормально. Не стоит забывать про все прекрасные возможности и глюки отображения, которых бы не было, если б не этот скачок технологий. Читай про `<viewport>`, например, [тут](http://frontender.com.ua/mobile-web/wtf-viewport/) и ещё где-нибудь обязательно.

Для отлавливания **touch-событий** (gestures) советую заюзать упомянутый выше Hammer.js, но для нормального сайта будет достаточно и стандартных событий типа `click`. О самом необходимом разработчики девайсов сами позаботились.

[Здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/107764/) есть пара хороших заметок на эту тему.

Это не всё. Ещё как минимум о половине прелестей я не знаю.